# How to get tfs to notify affected developers of changes?

Tags: tfs

I'm on a small team and we are emailing each other when we make changes telling each other to get latest; pretty inefficient. And error prone.

How can we set up TFS to do this notify via email, perhaps with a change summary including the affected files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [alerts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) in TFS to setup those notifications.